# Where to find Rule based classification data

Tags: data-request

I was wondering whether I could find any rule based classification data. In the sense I want a data where the output classification is done based on rules.

> Example:
>
> Let `F1`, `F2`, `F3` be 3 numerical attributes and `Y` being the output column with classes `(0, 1)`. Say Y value will be `1` if and only if (`F1 > 0.6 or (F2 > 0.7 and F3 < 0.01))` else the value will always be `0`.

Can I find data sets with rules defined for classification?